# Why is this returning a NULL

Tags: c, pointers, null, char, return

I have something like the following source code in c:

```
char *get_str() {
    char *str; 
    int slen=get_strlen();
    str=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*slen);
    set_str(str);
    printf("returning str %s with len %d\n", str, strlen(str));
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char *str=get_str();
    printf("recieved str %s with len %d\n", str, strlen(str));
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
returning str hi with len 2
received str with len 0
```

This is driving me nuts. The "returning str" statement has exactly what it should, but the "received str" keeps coming back null. I have verified that slen is non-zero. The function that sets the string is part of a large and widely used software package, so can be assumed to set the string correctly.

EDIT:

As pointed out below, the information presented here wasn't sufficient to solve the problem. I also needed to point out that the the function get_str was in a different source code file. The problem ended up being that I forgot to add a line for get_str() to the header, which alk and Nitzan Shaked correctly guessed below. This did not result in a compile error because I am using an ansi c compiler, which just assumed that get_str would return an integer.

Comment: Please show `set_str`

Comment: Are `main()` and `get_str()` defined in the same compilation unit? Could it be that `char` means one thing where `get_str()` is defined, and another where `main()` is defined (say a wide-char, and that's why the presumed length is 0?)

Comment: Don't forget to allocate an extra spot for null terminator.

Comment: So we are to assume that `get_strlen()` returns a proper size of **3** (to include the terminator), that the unchecked and improperly cast `malloc()` is not failing, and that `set_str()` properly copies the same string used for calculation in `get_strlen()`? Just for kicks and giggles, try putting `get_strlen()` into that `printf()` rather than `strlen(str)` to see what was *actually allocated* if anything.

Comment: The code you're showing us can't possibly produce the result you're showing us, so there's something you're not showing us. (Also, he's right about the malloc() being a byte short--but that's not likely your problem).

Comment: For the sake of completness you might like to add to your question the compiler in use along with it's version and the envirnoment as well, please?

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah: "Try returning a character array instead of pointer." -- And how exactly would you do that? A C function cannot return an array.

Comment: *"I have something like the following source code ..."* -- We can't help you with your actual code unless you show it to us. In modifying your code for posting, you've probably removed whatever causes the problem you're seeing; after all, you **don't know** what causes it. Show us actual compilable runnable source code that exhibits the problem  you're seeing. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @NitzanShaked: `char` is a keyword. If it's redefined anywhere in the program, the OP has worse problems than what he's telling us about.

Comment: Actually the question's topic is wrong, it should be "*Why is this returning a `0`-length "string"*".

Comment: @KeithThompson: I never said it was redefined. It could be that one compilation unit was compiled for 32bit, and another for 64bit.

Comment: @NitzanShaked: They were not defined in the same compilation unit. That ended up being the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet this runs on a 64bit system and your code looks like this:

```
int main() {
    char *str=get_str();
    printf("received str %s with len %d\n", str, strlen(str));
}

char *get_str() {
    char *str; 
    int slen=get_strlen();
    str=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*slen);
    set_str(str);
    printf("returning str %s with len %d\n", str, strlen(str));
    return str;
}
```

To fix this, add the appropriate prototyping:

```
char *get_str();
```

**before** the function's first usage.

---

On (most?) 32bit systems pointer are 32bit wide, which is the same size as an `int` to which the compiler defaults the function as the prototpye is missing, so although using a wrong type the value gets pass back up successfully. The latter won't work anymore on a 64bit system as pointers (on most systems) are wider than an `int`.